# Matplotlib, override Y position with pixel position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the following charts with Matpltlib:
[image]

I would like to have the colored dots at a constant distance from the bottom of the charts.
However as you can see they jump all over the place as their y coordinate is given in y value, and the y axis is different in each chart. Is there a way to define their y position in pixels from the x axis? Without having to resort to % of (top of the chart - bottom of the chart) would be ideal. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can plot the points in axes coordinates instead of data coordinates. Axes coordinates range from 0 to 1 (lower left corner to upper right corner).

In order to use axes coordinates, you need to supply `Axes.transAxes` to the plot's `transform` argument - also see the [transformation tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html).

Here is a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,5,9], [456,894,347], "r-", 
         label="plot in data coordinates")
plt.plot([0.2,0.3,0.7], [0.2,0.2,0.5], "bo", 
         transform=plt.gca().transAxes, label="plot in axes coordinates")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

---

If you want to specify the horizontal coordinate in data coordinates, and the vertical one in axes coordinates, you can use a [blended transformation](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations),

```
matplotlib.transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
```

This can be used as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

ax = plt.gca()
plt.plot([12,25,48], [456,894,347], "r-", 
         label="plot in data coordinates")
plt.plot([0.2,0.3,0.7], [0.2,0.2,0.5], "bo", 
         transform=ax.transAxes, label="plot in axes coordinates")
#blended tranformation:
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
plt.plot([15,30,35], [0.75,0.25,0.5], "gs", markersize=12,
         transform=trans, label="plot x in data-,\ny in axes-coordinates")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thats great thx! However in my specific case I need to use the data coordinate for the x value and the axes coordinate for the y value. Is that possible?